# Simple list comprehension

Tags: python, object-oriented

As far as I can tell, there is no network access happening at this stage in the code. I am accessing Reddit's API via the PRAW module. However, it is crawling, and I think it should be faster, considering I am hardly doing any work (unless Python heavily penalizes object access?).

This is the **entire** short script:

```
import sys, os, pprint, praw

class Scanner(object):
    ''' A scanner object. '''
    def __init__(self):
        self.user_agent = 'debian.blah8899889.agent'
        self.r = praw.Reddit(user_agent=self.user_agent)
        self.nsfw = ('funny', 'nsfw')
        self.nsfw_posters = set()
        self.content = []

    def getSub(self, subreddit):
        ''' Accepts a subreddit. Adds subreddit posts object to self.content'''
        url = 'http://www.reddit.com/r/{sub}/'.format(sub=subreddit)
        print 'Scanning:', subreddit
        subreddit_posts = self.r.get_content(url, limit=5)
        self.addContent(subreddit_posts)

    def addContent(self, subreddit):
        print 'Adding subreddit posts to content.'
        self.content.append(subreddit)

    def addNSFWPoster(self, post):
        print 'Parsing author and adding to posters.'
        self.nsfw_posters.add(str(post.author))

    def scanNSFW(self):
        ''' Scans all NSFW subreddits. Makes list of posters. '''
#       Get content from all nsfw subreddits
        print 'Executing map function.'
        map(self.getSub, self.nsfw)
#       Scan content and get authors
        print 'Executing list comprehension.'
        [self.addNSFWPoster(post) for sub in self.content for post in sub]

def main():
    scan = Scanner()
    scan.scanNSFW()

main()
```

All of the network access should happen at `map(self.getSub, self.nsfw)`. This actually runs quite fast considering I am rate limited by Reddit's servers.

I cannot work out why the list comprehension is so slow. All it should be doing is iterating through some objects and extracting a simple attribute: it should merely get `str(post.author)`.

```
 [self.addNSFWPoster(post) for sub in self.content for post in sub]
```

Can someone help me understand why it seems so slow to execute?

I am new to the OOP approach, and I can only assume I have made a big mistake somewhere.
It is slower than the network access portion of the code!

Answer (score 4):

Well for starters with

```
[self.addNSFWPoster(post) for sub in self.content for post in sub]
```

you are constructing a list of

```
[None, None, ... , None]
```

with a length equal to

```
len(self.content) * len(sub)
```

that you are immediately throwing away because you aren't assigning it to a variable. In other words you should only use a list comprehension for building a list, not for calling a method that is doing work elsewhere.

An alternative implementation is as you might expect a nested for loop:

```
for sub in self.content:
    for post in sub:
        self.addNSFWPoster(post)
```

To speed this up further you could reduce your [function call overhead](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips) with the following:

```
for sub in self.content:
    for post in sub:
        print 'Parsing author and adding to posters.'
        self.nsfw_posters.add(str(post.author))
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't call `main()` directly from the program like this.  Place this call in an `if` block like this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This helps prevent problems created when you use multiple files, and is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do).

Answer (score 1):

> All of the network access should happen at map(self.getSub,
>   self.nsfw). This actually runs quite fast considering I am rate
>   limited by Reddit's servers.
>
> I cannot work out why the list comprehension is so slow. All it should
>   be doing is iterating through some objects and extracting a simple
>   attribute: it should merely get str(post.author).

See the PRAW docs on [Lazy Objects](https://praw.readthedocs.org/en/latest/pages/lazy-loading.html) and [`get_content`](https://praw.readthedocs.org/en/latest/pages/code_overview.html?highlight=get_content#praw.__init__.BaseReddit.get_content). Data is fetched from Reddit when it is needed in the list comprehension. `for post in sub` iterates over a generator returned from `get_content`.